# Word for the opposite of a [thing]-snob?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Looking for a word or phrase that implies you are not picky about the thing in question.

As in:

> Do you have any coffee?
>
> I'm out of coffee grounds, the only thing I have left is this half
>   empty pot of cold coffee from yesterday.
>
> That's fine, I'll just throw it in the microwave, I'm a _____

Comment: It would be hard to qualify with a noun, but the typically phrasing is, I think, *low maintenance* or *easy*.

Comment: also lowbrow, undemanding, I have simple tastes, I'm a simple man.

Comment: @P.Obertelli speaking of low-brow, the first thing that came to mind was "coffee-slut" but I was hoping for something slightly classier

Comment: "I'm easy" or "I'm easy to please" or simply, "I'm not picky" could work.

Comment: according to UD coffee slot can have near opposite meanings: "someone with a large amount of knowledge pertaining to said caffeinated beverage (usually pretentious)" vs "When you are not loyal to anyone or any place that serves up coffee." Which one you meant?

Comment: Maybe you could reduce the “thing” to its lowest component before finding a suitable opposite for “snob” to use with it: “I’m [just] a “caffeine-slut.” Before seeing your “slut” comment I thought of these: “I’m [just] a caffeine addict, not a coffee snob”/”I’m [just] an alcoholic, not a wine snob”/”I’m [just] a calorie addict, not a food snob.”

Comment: @P.Obertelli the first one in your example I think of as coffee-snob.  The second one is the one I am looking for a term for

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my own comment up as an answer since I think the other answers may be great, but not necessarily capturing the "not picky" aspect of the OP's question:

> Do you have any coffee?
>
> I'm out of coffee grounds, the only thing I have left is this half empty pot of cold coffee from yesterday.
>
> That's fine, I'll just throw it in the microwave, ***I'm easy***.

**or**

> Do you have any coffee?
>
> I'm out of coffee grounds, the only thing I have left is this half empty pot of cold coffee from yesterday.
>
> That's fine, I'll just throw it in the microwave, ***I'm easy to please***.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of a lot of things can be expressed by putting *not* in front of it. Nothing else came to mind after you mentioned coffee: (*Coffee connoisseur* yields a quarter million hits *"in quotes"* on Google.)

> That's fine, I'm not a [optional profanity] *connoisseur*.

**connoisseur** con·nois·seur /ˌkänəˈsər,ˌkänəˈso͝or/ noun –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=connoisseur%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

```
an expert judge in matters of taste.
```

Profanity would stress the fact that you think those who are, are snobs, and that you certainly aren't one of them. Personally, I think the most colloquial expression is already in the question: *I'm **not picky***.

Answer (score -1):

You may say "That's fine, I'll just throw it in the microwave **without any fuss**".

> "fuss" definition: an excessive display of anxious attention or
>   activity; needless or useless ceremonies.

**Coffee novice** or **coffee neophyte** may also fit, even if it doesn't exactly mean that you don't care about the drink taste.

Comment: Novice and neophyte aren't good for this situation, as you could have been drinking coffee for 20 years and still not care if it's a craft roast or not.